# New Acer Iconia tablet

Tags: acer-iconia-tab-10

This is a new tablet and it very slow . My previous Iconia was so much better.  It is only a few months old and I have very little stored on it.  Could I do a factory reset and is it likely to sort this out?  There is no stored data to worry about only apps and websites that I have downloaded.

Thank you.

Comment: can you tell the specs of that tablet? or the model number so we can check its tecnical specifications?

Comment: The label says Model A6003

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, resetting Samsung devices does make them faster, so resetting an Acer device will also likely make it faster.

If you don't have any important data stored, then its definitely worth trying to factory reset your tablet to see if it gets faster.

Comment: That is not a Samsung device, it seems.

Comment: Ya, I meant to say that since it makes Samsung devices faster, it should make your Acer tablet faster, guess I phrased my answer the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing Full Factory reset I did this once in my laggy phone and it doesn't lag Anymore